# NET MAUI 8.0 apps do not start any more on Windows with Visual Studio 17.8

Tags: visual-studio, maui

All apps are affected.

The program "[17256] LanguageLab.exe" has exited with code 2147958022 (0x80073d06).

The program "[19508] PopupWithFrame.exe" has exited with code 2147958022 (0x80073d06).

The usual steps such as deleting bin and obj folders do not help. This affects all projects. Even an empty project created by Visual Studio template does not run.

Everything worked well with Visual Studio 17.8.5 for quite a while until all of a sudden it did not work any more.
I work on  Windows 10, Version 22H2.

After I hit this error I've updated to Visual Studio 17.8.7. But this did not fix the problem.

I'm wondering if this issue is a general problem.

Comment: Can you run dotnet restore on the solution and check if that fixes your issue?

Comment: Either that, or try running `dotnet workload update` or `dotnet workload repair`, it could be that something is corrupted as a recent version of .NET *(8.0.200)* attempts to install [incorrect workload](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20600) versions *(could be related?)*

Comment: Thank you FreakyAli, thank you @Julian.
I used View -> Terminal to open the developer Power Shell and I tried:
dotnet restore /

dotnet workload update /

dotnet workload repair /

But unfortunately it did not change for the better.

I even uninstalled the latest Windows Service Pack (KB5034763) and installed Visual Studio 17.9. 
I still cannot start any Windows app.

Comment: This problem is very persistent!
After updating to Visual Studio 17.9 I was on .NET 8.0.200. To avoid the known error 'incorrect Workload' (see the comment of Julian) I updated to SDK  8.0.201 with the following Power Shell script:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/scripts/v1/dotnet-install.ps1
But this error does not go away.

Comment: Did you meet the same problem on another VS version? such as Visual Studio Preview.

Comment: @Sean He-MSFT: Visual Studio Code works fine. I wanted to switch to Visual Studio Code anyhow, because I need a MacBook to test and deploy on IOS. But I keep an eye on this problem. Maybe after all I will find what the problem is.

Comment: I found you did not mention that you have tried unload the  VS and reinstall it. Did you try this method?

Comment: @Sean He-MSFT: I removed Visual Studio 2022 today along with VS 2017 and VS 2015. Then I made an installation from scratch. I am now on VS 17.9.1 with a brand new installation.
Same problem as before! 
All my Windows Apps crash on start-up.
It is even worse: All .NET MAUI programs that I have created over the past years on my PC, do not work any more. When I right click on the icon of my app in the Windows Start menu and click More -> App settings the App size has 0 Bytes.

Comment: Is there only the problem with MAUI project? Are other types of projects also unable to run, such as Xamarin.forms or Blazor Web App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. I added

`<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>`

to a `PropertyGroup` in the project file, it solved the issue.

Of course, this has an impact on your application's size, but at least you can continue working in Visual Studio until it gets fixed. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @András Földesi. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has gone away after installation of Visual Studio 19.9.2.
Using VS 17.9.1 with a brand new installation of Visual Studio did not work but VS 17.9.2 fixed the problem.
All .NET MAUI programs that I have created over the past years on my PC work again without any change.
Dotnet --version displays 8.0.200. So there is no need to install SDK 8.0.201.
The Windows update (KB5034763) of Windows 10 Version 22H2 was not harmful because I've re-installed it and everything is fine.